# Jquery Slider Month/Year

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code and it is currently displaying the date in the following format on the slider : Tue Jan 01 2013 - Wed Jan 01 2014, However, I am wanting it to display in the following format if possible 01/2015 - 01/2018 I am insure of what to change to allow me to achieve this.
Thanks

```
$(function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
      range: true,
      min: new Date('January 2012 00:0:00').getTime() / 1000,
      max: new Date('January 2019 00:0:00').getTime() / 1000,
      step: 86400,
      values: [ new Date('January 2013 00:0:00').getTime() / 1000, new Date('January 01, 2014 00:0:00').getTime() / 1000 ],
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( (new Date(ui.values[ 0 ] *1000).toDateString() ) + " - " + (new Date(ui.values[ 1 ] *1000)).toDateString() );
      }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( (new Date($( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 )*1000).toDateString()) +
      " - " + (new Date($( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 )*1000)).toDateString());

  });
```

Answer (score 4):

The `new Date()` has invalid date time format, change it to `'yyyy-mm-ddThh:min:ss'`, then it should work.

Check [JavaScript Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to figure out how to construct one Date object.

```js
$(function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
      range: true,
      min: new Date('2012-01-01T00:00:00').getTime() / 1000,
      max: new Date('2019-01-01T00:00:00').getTime() / 1000,
      step: 864,
      values: [ new Date('2012-03-01T00:00:00').getTime() / 1000, new Date('2014-01-01T00:00:00').getTime() / 1000 ],
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( (new Date(ui.values[ 0 ] *1000).toDateString() ) + " - " + (new Date(ui.values[ 1 ] *1000)).toDateString() );
      }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( (new Date($( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 )*1000).toDateString()) +
      " - " + (new Date($( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 )*1000)).toDateString());

  });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  
  <p>
  <label for="amount">date range:</label>
  <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;width:400px;">
</p>
 
<div id="slider-range"></div>
```

**Update:** below is the simple month/year ranger, The primary modifications are  adjust some description texts and the date format.

```js
function formatDate(date) {
  var monthNames = [
    "January", "February", "March",
    "April", "May", "June", "July",
    "August", "September", "October",
    "November", "December"
  ];

  var monthIndex = date.getMonth();
  var year = date.getFullYear();

  return monthNames[monthIndex] + ' ' + year;
}

$(function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
      range: true,
      min: new Date('2012-01-01T00:00:00').getTime(),
      max: new Date('2019-01-01T00:00:00').getTime(),
      step: 86400000,
      values: [ new Date('2012-03-01T00:00:00').getTime(), new Date('2014-01-01T00:00:00').getTime() ],
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( formatDate(new Date(ui.values[0])) + '-' + formatDate(new Date(ui.values[1])) );
      }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( formatDate((new Date($( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 )))) +
      " - " + formatDate((new Date($( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 )))));

  });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  
  <p>
  <label for="amount">month range:</label>
  <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;width:400px;">
</p>
 
<div id="slider-range"></div>
```

Comment: Hello sorry for some confusion, on the slider and when it stores the data I am wanting it to store / display the it as Month/Year instead of Day Month date year, is that possible?

Comment: @Savage, just simply modified the codes to implement month/year ranger. You need to optimize it by yourself.

Comment: I've tried however I'm struggling to do so, I tried and I couldn't figure it out which is why I asked, I changed the obvious things but it messed around with my slider.

Comment: @Savage, above two snippets doesn't meet your requirements? If not, let me know what you actually need. Do you mean you'd like the attributes (min, max, values) are string like `min=2017-01; max=2019-02; values=['2017-01', '2019-2']` ?