# JQuery Month slider is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I am referring [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49019174/jquery-slider-month-year) article and trying to create a month slider without range. I want to remove range from this slider as I just need a month and year. Please find below my updated code.

```js
    function formatDate(date) {
      var monthNames = [
        "January", "February", "March",
        "April", "May", "June", "July",
        "August", "September", "October",
        "November", "December"
      ];
    
      var monthIndex = date.getMonth();
      var year = date.getFullYear();
    
      return monthNames[monthIndex] + ' ' + year;
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#range-slider").slider({
          range: "min",
          min: new Date('2012-01-01T00:00:00').getTime(),
          max: new Date('2019-01-01T00:00:00').getTime(),
          step: 86400000,
          value:new Date('2015-03-01T00:00:00').getTime() ,
            slide: function(event, ui) {
        
                $( "#amount" ).val( formatDate(new Date(ui.values[1])));
            }
        });
    
    });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  
<p>
  <label for="amount">date range:</label>
  <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;width:400px;">
</p>
 
<div id="range-slider"></div>
```

It works fine if I replace

`value:new Date('2015-03-01T00:00:00').getTime() ,`

to

```
values: [ new Date('2015-03-01T00:00:00').getTime(),new Date('2015-03-01T00:00:00').getTime() ],
```

Please let me know what is wrong in this code.

Comment: Do you need just "12months' name" or "month name  + Year" ?

Comment: @saAction I need both "month name + Year"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function formatDate(date) {
      var monthNames = [
        "January", "February", "March",
        "April", "May", "June", "July",
        "August", "September", "October",
        "November", "December"
      ];
    
      var monthIndex = date.getMonth();
      var year = date.getFullYear();
    
      return monthNames[monthIndex] + ' ' + year;
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#range-slider").slider({
          range: "min",
          min: new Date('2012-01-01T00:00:00').getTime(),
          max: new Date('2019-01-01T00:00:00').getTime(),
          step: 86400000,
          value:new Date('2015-03-01T00:00:00').getTime() ,
            slide: function(event, ui) {
                // There was a mistake here
                // $( "#amount" ).val( formatDate(new Date(ui.values[1])));

                $( "#amount" ).val( formatDate(new Date(ui.value)));
            }
        });
    
    });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  
<p>
  <label for="amount">date range:</label>
  <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;width:400px;">
</p>
 
<div id="range-slider"></div>
```

Try this :)

Answer (score 1):

You want to get "Month - Year" view

Try this:

```js
function formatDate(date) {
  var monthNames = [
    "January", "February", "March",
    "April", "May", "June", "July",
    "August", "September", "October",
    "November", "December"
  ];

  var monthIndex = date.getMonth();
  var year = date.getFullYear();

  return monthNames[monthIndex] + ' ' + year;
}

$(function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
      range: false,
      min: new Date('2012-01-01T00:00:00').getTime(),
      max: new Date('2019-01-01T00:00:00').getTime(),
      step: 86400000,
      values: [new Date('2018-08-18T00:00:00').getTime()],
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( formatDate(new Date(ui.values[0])) );
      }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( formatDate((new Date($( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 )))));

  });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  
  <p>
  <label for="amount">date range:</label>
  <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;width:400px;">
</p>
 
<div id="slider-range"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment but As I mentioned above, I just need a month and year not range selection.

Comment: jQuery US "slider-range" need to point "A" to "B", if you need only selector without any range, you need something else.

Comment: I mean to say, I need just one handle to select the month from slider as we can see here. https://jqueryui.com/slider/

Comment: @John, code is change, now there is single slider element, I hope this is what you want!