# CSS only range input for months

Tags: css

I want a range input for months. I have a range slider displaying the current value using `<input>` and `<output>`, but haven't come up with a CSS only way to show month abbreviations instead of month numbers. Any ideas?

```
<form name="myform" oninput="show_month.value = get_month.valueAsNumber">
  <div>
    <output name="show_month" for="get_month" >6</output>
    <input name="get_month" type="range" step="1" min="1" max="12" value="6">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you share the snippet?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49019174/jquery-slider-month-year I think this will help you.

Comment: Please include your working code. thanks.

Comment: Snippet added above.  I want to display the month (Jan, Feb, ...) instead of the month number.  @ParthRaval, thanks for the link, but I'm looking for a CSS only solution.

Comment: Why CSS only? This doesn't seem like a thing CSS should be doing. And I doubt it can, since CSS doesn't look at content. Plus you need to use JavaScript to write the  month to the `output` element anyway, so why not write the name of the month instead of the number?

Answer (score 1):

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = months[0];

slider.oninput = function() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = months[slider.value];
}
```

```css
.slidecontainer {
  width: 100%;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="0" max="11" value="0" class="slider" id="myRange">
  <output><span id="demo"></span></output>
</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate the example, but I'm looking for a CSS only solution.

Comment: @shyam-sundar, Please include an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post

Comment: @SaeedZhiany, Thank you for pointing this out. I am new to Stackoverflow and still figuring my way. 
This is a pretty basic range slider. I just added a switch case to pass the required string to <output>.
(slider.value) in the switch case contains the range value and based on its respective case will be executed.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please consider to add your description in your answer body, not in the comment section. by that, your description getting more attention.

Comment: At the very least you should be using an array instead a huge switch.

Comment: Whee. Somehow added code snippet. Still wondering how to add description after posting the answer. 
@RoToRa. Thank you for the suggestion. Changed code accordingly.

Comment: You've got a bug now: `slider.value` is a string, that starts with `"1"`, but you need a number starting with `0`. A range input provides the value as a number with the property `valueAsNumber`: `... = months[slider.valueAsNumber - 1];`.

Comment: Some more points: Prefer assigning event handlers with `addEventListener`, instead of using `on...`  attributes or you'll be in danger of overwriting (or be overwritten by) other event handlers. And don't set the default value to "January", it could be something else. Instead call the event handler during initialization to set the correct initail value.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the approach I'm taking:

```
<script>
  month_abbr = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"]
</script>

<form name="myform" oninput="show_month.value = month_abbr[get_month.valueAsNumber - 1]">
  <div>
    <output name="show_month" for="get_month" >Jun</output>
    <input name="get_month" type="range" step="1" min="1" max="12" value="6">
  </div>
</form>
```

Thanks to @RoToRa for making me think about the problem differently.

If I can do something with either CSS or javascript, I'll use CSS.  I find it cleaner, more stable, and easier to maintain.  It's a personal preference and YMMV.  Yes, I understand the snippet above uses a little javascript.